# Who were the eyewitnesses mentioned by name who were still living to the audience of the book/letter in question?

Tags: new-testament

My wife and I are wracking our Brains, and we cannot remember where the reference is or who the reference is about, but there is somewhere in the New Testament that mentions people who were eyewitnesses of Jesus and that they were still among the believers at the time of the writing.  Does anyone know where this is located?

Comment: Maybe you are thinking of the 500 mentioned in [1 Corinthians 15:6](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/bi22/E/1901/46/15#h=289:282-289:412&s=6&study=parallel) of whom Paul wrote that the greater part was still alive at the time when he wrote that letter to the Corinthians. Most of these were not mentioned by name though.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE, and thanks for taking the site tour. For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394). Meanwhile, I hope you'll browse some of the other questions and answers on this site.

Answer (score 2):

You are certainly thinking of [1 Corinthians 15: 4-7](http://biblehub.com/kjv/1_corinthians/15.htm) where the Apostle St. Paul speaks about 500 eyewitnesses of which some were still living and names all the Apostles as witnesses also.

> And that he was buried, and that he rose again the third day according to the scriptures: And that he was seen of **Cephas**, then of the twelve: After that, he was seen of above five hundred brethren at once; of whom the greater part remain unto this present, but some are fallen asleep. After that, he was seen of **James**; then of all the apostles. And last of all he was seen of me also, as of one born out of due time.

Comment: Thank you!  Given my question, your answer does make sense and is another great example of witnesses early readers of the New Testament could have talked with.  That said, we have figured out what we were looking for.  It turned out to be a mixture of Scripture and Commentary that we had read.  The specific verse we were looking for was from Mark 15:21.  Mark talks of Rufus and Alexander.  The commentary stated that the reason for the inclusion of their names was to point to a contemporary the readers could verify the story with.  In any case, thanks again.